# What is the most recent correct syntax to initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK in the App Delegate file?

Tags: xcode, swift4

All of a sudden, I get a warning on the code used to initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK. (It had been working for weeks before with no warning, but now it seems there's a new way to write the code.)

This is the code I have:

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-################~##########")
```

But it gives me this warning: 'configure(withApplicationID:)' is deprecated: Use [GADMobileAds.sharedInstance startWithCompletionHandler:]

I've tried to rewrite it like this (with and without the square brackets):

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance startWithCompletionHandler: "ca-app-pub-################~##########"
```

But it just gives me an error that it expected a ;.

How should I write this? Thank you!

[image: files from Pods folder in Xcode show a modified status]

Comment: do you know if we get consent before or after initializing SDK ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1) Add the follow in Info.plist

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>
```

2) in AppDelegate

```
 GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! That seems to have worked. (I put in my own ca-app-pub- number of course :D)

Comment: do you know if we get consent before or after initializing SDK ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but I later did find the source of Muhammad's knowledge: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start 

Maybe the answer is on that page @izzyMachado?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Sr, it worked for me on Xamarin, just I need it to make some little changes on the code as follow:

```
GADMobileAds.SharedInstance.Start(completionHandler: null)
```